# what is the difference between using insert function when using std::map.insert("xyz") or just map[ind]="xyz"

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, dictionary, insert

In the following example what is the pros and cons of using 1) versus 2).  Is there any memory allocation benefits, any benefits as far as not running out of space?

```
map <  int, string> Employees;  



  // 1) Assignment using array index notation  

   Employees[5234] = "Mike C.";  

  // 2) Assignment using member function insert() and STL pair  

    Employees.insert(std::pair<int, * char>(1923,"David D."));
```

Answer (score 5):

The first creates a mapping with key 5234 and returns a reference to the string held there, to which "Mike C" gets assigned - important point is, if the key already exists, this will **overwrite** the value at that key (because a reference to the value is returned).

The second approach checks to see if the key is present, and will not overwrite if it does already exist.

As for memory allocation, both will increase the map size by 1 if the mapping does not exist. The above is the only difference between the two approaches AFAIK.

Comment: Effective STL, item 24 - there might be an observable speed difference between these two. In the operator[] there is an extra copy. But: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#334

Comment: @Anonymous: just out of curiosity: Why did they not suggest using the uniform initializer constructor as an alternative to `make_pair`? Wouldn't that avert the extra copy?

Answer (score 4):

The difference here is that option 1 will assign the value to the key in all cases, where option two can return an std::pair containing the iterator of the item, plus a boolean notification of the insert success. What this means is that if item 1923 already exists in your map, the insert function would return `<iterator, false>`, notifying you that the key already exists in the map and **will not** overwrite it.

```
std::map<int, char*> aMap;
aMap[12] = "An Entry";

std::pair< std::map<int, char*>::iterator, bool > result;
result = aMap.insert(12, "A new entry");

//now result.first points to the existing entry at 12, result.second == false
```

The only performance benifit I can think of here is that you're saving processing time by not doing an `if(aMap.count(12) == 0)` or `if(aMap.find(12) == aMap.end())` before performing an insert operation.

Answer (score 4):

- If `key` does **not** exist in the map, then `Employees[key] = value` **adds** a new key-value pair to the map.
- If `key` already exists, then `Employees[key] = value` simply **updates** the value with the given key.
- `Employees.insert()` always **adds** a new key-value pair to the map. However, if the key already exists, it does nothing. If you want to allow different elements to have the same key, then you can use [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/).

Comment: I dont understand your last point? Will it add some kind of empty item?

Answer (score 1):

You can read in details in "Effective STL" book by Scott Meyers (topic 24).

Answer (score 1):

Very useful to know this difference between `insert` and `operator[]`

You can actually implement `operator[]` in terms of `insert`, as it returns `pair<iterator,bool>`

Thus one could (and possibly would) implement:

```
Value& map<K,T>::operator[]( const Key& key )
{
   return insert( make_pair(key, Value()) ).first->second;
}
```

A practical application in use:
In a typical "lazy load" cache situation you may have `map<Key, shared_ptr<Value> >`

A programmer will typically start with find thus:

```
  const_iterator iter = theMap.find(key);
  if( iter!= theMap.end())
     return iter->second;
  else
  {
    // create the item then insert it
  }
```

A better approach is:

```
shared_ptr<Value> value = theMap[key];
if( !value )
{
   value.reset( /*load logic */ )
}
return value;
```

In a multi-threaded situation of the above, instead of shared_ptr use a wrapper class that implements "boost::once" logic. Let's say that the loading of the object takes a long time. In the classic case you would probably lock the entire map whilst you look up the item and then create it. So no other thread can use the map at all.

Instead we now lock the map just for the lookup and create the object in its "ONCE_INIT" state. We then unlock the map and use `boost::call_once` to initialise the actual item. Note that during this time it is possible that a different thread created the item than the one that added it to the map, but it makes no real difference: it will be created exactly once and there is no thread contention. (This is an implementation of record-level locking). Note that if we used the first construct (find then insert) we would not be able to do this.